# Correct Exception to throw when a duplicate key insertion is attempted?

Tags: java, exception

Repeatedly I see comments about avoiding throwing generic `RuntimeException` and I am trying to follow that guideline.

I have a class that aggregates a `SortedMap` with a property setting to allow or disallow duplicate keys.  I am trying to figure out what Exception I should throw when duplicate keys are disallowed and an attempt is made to add one.

I checked the Java docs for the `Exception` class and none of the known direct descendants seemed suitable.  Do I just go ahead and create my own `EDuplicateMapKey` class for example and throw that?  If so, how do I avoid ending up with a big pile of class files, one for each custom `Exception` type?

What is considered "best practice" here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create your own exception. For example Java EE has [`DuplicateKeyException`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/DuplicateKeyException.html), you can do something similar as that for your custom map.

Answer (score 5):

> Do I just go ahead and create my own EDuplicateMapKey class for example and throw that?

Absolutely, yes. DOn't be afraid to create new exception types if it feels like the right way to go. If it's not clear to you, as the author, which is the right exception type to use, then it certainly won't be clear to the programmer using your API. So make it explicit, and create your own exception type.

> How do I avoid ending up with a big pile of class files, one for each custom Exception type?

Exception classes are no different to any other business logic type. You don't feel restrained in creating as many types as you feel is necessary for your "normal" code (at least, I hope you don't), and you should feel no differently when it comes to exception types.  They're often just as important.

Answer (score 5):

*Personally*, [IllegalStateException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) or [IllegalArgumentException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) looks like it could work here but I can see arguments against that too.

Comment: RuntimeException subclasses are unchecked. This means that throw declarations and try/catch is not neccesary. As such, RuntimeException subclasses are generally considered to be things that shouldn't be able to happen (logic/programmer error) rather than something conceivable that should be handled gracefully (such as I/O failure) because of the lack of enforcement in having to deal with it. Conversely, it's clumsy having to try/catch for things that shouldn't be logically possible.

So on the contrary, if you want to force dealing with it then subclass anything but RuntimeException.

Comment: @SamSvenbjorgchristiensensen: "Checked exceptions can sometimes be useful if you are writing a critical library[...] but in general application development, the depencency cost outweigh the benifits" Chapter 7 of Clean Code by Martin

Comment: What you said was that *given that you want to force the programmer to deal with it in a special manner (i.e. catch)*, use an unchecked exception (which are subclasses of RuntimeException). This is materially incorrect, not a matter of opinion or style, because it is precisely RuntimeException and its subclasses which *don't* force the use of try/catch.

I appreciate that the quote is probably good advice, but it's not talking about the same thing.

I agree that an unchecked exception seems appropriate in this particular case, and IllegalArgumentException seems reasonable.

Comment: +1 Another RuntimeException that might be useful in this case is [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html).  Other advice: I'll encapsulate the SortedMap inside a class and create a method to add something - otherwise one will have to remember to check for duplicates EVERYWHERE that something is put inside the SortedMap (versus just doing it once inside the class encapsulating the SortedMap).

Comment: Alternatively extend SortedMap and override the `put` method - write your duplicate-prevention logic and then delegate to the superclass `put` method.