# What is the conventional Java exception for "Too Many Results"

Tags: java, exception

I am writing a generic API that takes parameters and returns results. I expect that if the data is consistent, only one result will be returned for an ID. If I get 1 result, I return it. If I get 0 results, I can throw "MissingResourceException" or "NoSuchElementException" etc. However, if I get multiple results, what should I throw?  I have looked at the obvious places (Oracle/Java API documentation, Googling it, and of course, StackOverflow), but didn't find one.

Please note that I may not control the data, so the "the data should have been good/police your data" advice, while valid, will not help me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException ?

Comment: The word "Duplicate" springs to my mind. e.g.. "DuplicateEntryException" or something like that.  You really ought to strive to prevent this from happening which is why you would get stuff like ConcurrentModificationExceptions etc.

Comment: Well, the result depends on the given arguments. So why not throw an [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)? You can specify the error message with [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html#IllegalArgumentException-java.lang.String-), describing that the given arguments lead to ambiguous results.

Comment: @ShivV Thanks. I am more interested in a native Java exception, not one from another library.

Comment: If you need "native" Java exception, I think it should be "IllegalStateException"

Comment: @Turing85 believe me, I was tempted to use it myself, however, it does not fit the use-case. I will use it however, if all else fails. Please post your comment as an answer so I can up-vote it.

Comment: @Andrei_N, Same reasoning as IllegalArgumentException". The caller is not "wrong", the data is.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636371/correct-exception-to-throw-when-a-duplicate-key-insertion-is-attempted

Comment: @stark, thanks! That still requires EJB that don't need.

Comment: Looks like my own Exception will have to do, much as I dislike it.

Comment: Simply define your own exception: `class TooManyResultsException extends Exception ....`

Comment: @kordirko thanks. I understand how to define Java Exceptions, I was simply following Joshua Bloch's advice on reusing Exception classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java* says in Item 60 (**Favor to use standard exceptions**):

> Also, feel free to subclass an existing exception if you want to add a bit more failure-capture information (Item 63).

So, I vote for one of `IllegalStateException` or `YourOwnException` (with additional failure-related info).

Comment: I am seeing the logic of your argument for using "IllegalStateException", as the store (DB etc.) is in an illegal state. Thanks!

Comment: We can also use IndexOutOfBoundsException("Too many results found") with the message. Hope it helps.

Comment: It has been used in AbstractList class rangeCheckForAdd method just for your reference.